# Minimal Herbrand model

Tags: prolog

Given the following prolog program:

```
way(a,b,c).
way(a,d,e).
way(b,f,g).
way(f,h,i).
way(h,j,k).
way(l,j,m).
reachable(a, []).
reachable(X, [W|WS]) :- reachable(Y, WS), way(Y,X,W).
```

What is the minimal herbrand model using T-operator?

Let *I* be an interpretation, then:

```
I_0 = \emptyset
I_1 = T_P(I_0) = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,I,j,k,l,m} // all constants
I_2 = T_P(I_1) = I_1 \cup {way(a,b,c), way(a,d,e), way(b,f,g), way(f,h,i), way(h,j,k), way(l,j,m), reachable(a, [])}
```

But now I don't know how to continue. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reachable/2` is a recursive predicate. What you have to do is to apply the last rule until the interpretation remains the same after the application.

```
I_3 = T_P(I_2) = I_2 \cup {reachable(b, [c]),reachable(d, [e])}
I_4 = T_P(I_3) = I_3 \cup {reachable(f, [g,c])}
....
I_6 = T_P(I_5) = I_5 \cup {reachable(j, [k,i,g,c])}
I_7 = T_P(I_6) = I_6
```

Intuitively an element `X` is reachable if there exists `Y` that is reachable and there is a `way(Y,X,W)` for some `W`. This `W` is added to the second argument after the application of the rule.

You may now explicitly enumerate all elements in `I_6` to obtain the minimal model.